# Jenkins Error: "Unknown stage section "stage". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a 'steps' block

Tags: jenkins

Per my header, I'm receiving the following error for my jenkins setup:

```
Unknown stage section "stage". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a 'steps' block. @line xxx, column xx.
stage('First Parallel Stage') {
^
```

My configuration:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Header_1'){
            steps{}
        }
        stage('Header_2'){
            steps{}
        }
        parallel{
            stage('First Parallel Stage'){
                environment{}
            }
            stages {
                stage('Another_One'){
                    steps{}
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

I've tried putting an empty steps{} in stage('First Parallel Stage') and tried putting it inside steps. I'm unsure what could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure `parallel { stages { stage` is allowed. Looking at the [sample](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) it should be `parallel { stage { stages {`

Comment: It is currently parallel stage{ stages {

Comment: `parallel` needs to be within a stage. `stage('parallel') { parallel {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to put stages that are grouped together into a stage and parallel must be within a stage too. Full working example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Header_1') {
            steps {
                echo '1'
            }
        }
        stage('Header_2') {
            steps {
                echo '2'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Parallel') { // add this
            parallel {
                stage('First Parallel Stage') {
                    environment {
                        TEST = 3
                    }
                    
                    steps {
                        echo "$TEST"
                    }
                }
                
                stage('Execute this together') { // add this
                    stages {
                        stage('Another_One') {
                            steps {
                                echo "4"
                            }
                        }
                        
                        stage('Yet Another_One') {
                            steps {
                                echo "5"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that you can't have `parallel{}` inside of `parallel{}`, but you can chain them¹.

On BlueOcean it then looks like the following:

[image]

¹: Edit 2023: [This answer explains how it is possible through workarounds.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72988038/1651839)

Comment: you don't need the whole Blue Ocean baggae to visualize pipelines, you can try the new [Pipeline Graph View](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-graph-view/) plugin