# Is it possible to "step over" a jenkins step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a current pipeline consisting of various parallel steps like below

[image: current steps]

The thing is, from the total of ~15 minutes ~6 minutes is taken by the **red** step. This step is dependant on the cache of the **green** step and should be done before the **blue** step.

I've tried to build something with nested parallel steps like below

[image: try with nested parallel steps]

But jenkins was not happy with nested parallel steps and did not even start the pipeline

Is it possible to do nested parallel steps in jenkins?

Would it be possible to "skip" this **red** step and keep it running but still require it before the **blue** step starts?

Comment: An option: move the red step into a different job. Then you have more flexibility around how and when you get the job to run.

Comment: But I do need it before running the blue step

Comment: Hmm you *can* set the `wait: true,` option when the build is triggered to ensure that the pipeline waits for the job to complete first. But this might eventually result in you having to distribute all your stages into jobs.

Comment: @Xiduzo Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72988038/2627018

Comment: holy-moly, that's what I am looking for! Will give it a try, thanks!